# productsRequest not getting called

Tags: ios, ios7, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing inApp in my app, but after `[self.productsRequest start];`, no response is being received.

Here are the two files containing the complete codes for the Inapp Purchase:
[k7inApp.h](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/k7InApp.h)
[k7inApp.m](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/k7InApp.m)

Because I'm using ARC, i'm retaining both

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SKPayment *payment;
```

To check if there any error, I'm implementing the error function:

```
- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error while returning response");
}
```

Yet, this is also not getting called
Any ssuggestion, the application is crashing with exe_bad_access error?

Comment: use breakpoint to find out where it breaks

Comment: the app breaks after sometime after calling [self.productRequest start]

Comment: Use exception break point - it will stop exactly in place where it crashes

Comment: I'm adding one, which catches all exception, yet after it is returning on return UIApplicationMain.......

Comment: here is the file containing the full codes for the inapp purchase: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/k7InApp.m